# Unable to upload file by sendkeys into button element within iframe using selenium with python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[Environment]: Python + Selenium

I am trying to upload a local file to the upload file button.

First of all, I tried to see if I can locate that element and click on that button and I succeed by using

```
driver.switch_to_frame("upload_frame")
driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'id_file').click()
```

So, I used the same way but replace the `click()` with `send_keys()` for file uploading.

```
driver.switch_to_frame("upload_frame")
driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'id_file').send_keys("xxx.bin")
```

But it can not pass the value in.

So, I tried to use other locator as following: (None of them can work)

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Update from File']")
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='id_file']")
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='file']")
```

In addition, I also googled it with so many similar questions but unable to find a solution/answer.

Would like to seek your advice and shed me some light on this?
Thank you.

HTML codesnippet:

```
<iframe id="upload_frame" height="30px" frameborder="0" width="0" src="/web/setting/upload.html?r=1422498136526" scrolling="no"
name="upload_frame" style="width: 170px;">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>

        <body onload="page_load();">
            <div id="content" class="b1">
                <form id="form_firm" action="/cgi-bin/system_mgr.cgi" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="form_firm">
                    <input type="hidden" value="cgi_firmware_upload" name="cmd">
                    <div class="file_input_div">
                        <button id="id_file" type="button" style="border: 2px solid rgb(70, 70, 70); background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(33, 33, 33);">
                            <span class="_text" lang="_firmware" datafld="update_b">Update from File</span>
                        </button>
                        <input id="file" class="file_input_hidden" type="file" onchange="start_upload();" onclick="clear_upload_path();" style="cursor:pointer"
                        name="file">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>

    </html>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'id_file').send_keys("xxx.bin")` won't work as it corresponds to the `button element` not the `input element` with type file.

**For simple file upload using selenium, you must first search for the input tag with type as file. As in your code, that must be**:

`<input id="file" class="file_input_hidden" type="file" onchange="start_upload();" onclick="clear_upload_path();" style="cursor:pointer" name="file">`

Please use the below code for the file-upload to work:

```
driver.switch_to_frame("upload_frame")
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'file').send_keys('//path of the file to upload')
```

**Note:-** The above corresponds to the **"input tag with type file"**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that send_keys() needs to be used with input tag. Now, it works by using "file" id.  Appreciate that!!

Comment: Hi, Subh
Do you know how to send the file if the input type is NOT "file" but "button" instead?

I used the same way to send the filename into the element which is located by ID but it seemed not to work.