# Selenium upload file button throws "webDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element" while using "send_keys"

Tags: python, selenium, nose

I'm getting the error below when using "send_keys" for a choose file button in selenium in Python, using Chrome Driver:

```
webDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

After some research, I tried to use the action chain method:

```
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(e)
actions.send_keys("C:\Users\devuser\Desktop\Untitled.png")
actions.perform()
```

This executes with no error, however, the file is not uploaded. Any idea how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Update:
The html is below:

```
<div class="qq-upload-button" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr;">Upload Image
   <input multiple="multiple" type="file" name="file" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;">
</div>
```

Comment: any specific reason to use `actions` class here ?  directly `element.send_keys("C:\Users\devuser\Desktop\Untitled.png")` not working ?

Comment: I guess there is no html code like `<input type='file'...>` for the concerned 'upload file' button. So, [normal upload using sendkeys](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28206771/4193730) will not work. So, you might have to use something similar to [Robot class](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/15730/22560) (as in java), or Sikuli or AutoIt..

Comment: @NarendraRajput ya it doesnt work, it throws the error in the description.

Comment: @Subh updated the html code in the question.

Comment: Thanks. So, which element are you sending the image path to ? The outer `div` or the `input` tag inside it?

Comment: @Subh the input

Comment: This piece of code will help you out. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/11872608/4193730](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11872608/4193730)